# What do these expressions using logical operators inside while-loop mean?

Tags: r, while-loop, logical-operators

I am trying to understand a piece of code in R while loop and would be grateful if someone can help me out. I read the explanation for R logical operators in many online forums (and google search) but wasn't able to understand the below code.

Suppose:

```
c=1

while(c<=4){

  c1=c-(c>2)*2    
  c2=1*(c<3)+2*(c>2)        

  AB=A[[c1]] * ((1-x)+x*B[[c2]])               
  c=c+1
}
```

I am only interested to understand the following.

```
c1=c-(c>2)*2     

c2=1*(c<3)+2*(c>2)
```

I haven't seen such kind of combination of logical operators before and would be thankful if someone can explain it a bit. Many thanks.

Comment: Please use "code formatting"; it makes the question much more readable.

Comment: `c1=c-(c>2)*2 `for instance  has the same meaning as it would in maths.

Comment: `c > 2` will produce a logical, and when the logical is combined with an arithmetic operator like `*` it'll be cast to an appropriate numeric type, so in effect you're getting `1 * 2` or `0 * 2` in the first line

Comment: First off, your code is not reproducible for anyone but yourself (for example, `A` and `B` are not defined anywhere). More generally: Have you tried running the code step-by-step? You should add `print` statements to see what each of the variables is doing at every step of the `while` loop.

Comment: Many thanks for all the comments. I have finally understood it. Have a good day

Comment: Please add code that defines `A,B` (presumably matrices/dataframes), to make this reproducible; using toy or random values is fine. Otherwise this is likely to be closed.

Comment: Also, `c=1; while(c<=4) { ...; c=c+1 }` is just a badly obfuscated way of saying `for (c in 1:4) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another often sensible step towards understanding what a particular code line or function does is to graph it; since your `while` loop simply increments `c` each step and then calculates `c1` and `c2` based on those `c` values, we can write two functions

```
func_c1 <- function(c) c - (c > 2) * 2
func_c2 <- function(c) 1 * (c < 3) + 2 * (c > 2)
```

that return `c1` and `c2` respectively, for different values `c`.

We can then plot `c1` and `c2` for different values `c`; your `while` loop considers `c = 1:4`:

```
data.frame(c = 1:4, c1 = func_c1(1:4), c2 = func_c2(1:4)) %>%
    gather(param, val, -c) %>%
    ggplot(aes(c, val, colour = param)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_line()
```

[image]